# AttributeError, 'AnimalType' has no attribute 'animals_set'

Tags: python, django

I get an AttributeError for some reason. "'Animal Type' has no attribute 'animals_set'" Here is the model its referring to:

```
class AnimalType(models.Model):
    """Type of animal that can classify the animal"""
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    a_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.a_type

class Animal(models.Model):
    """The actual animal, embeded in animaltype"""
    animal_type = models.ForeignKey(AnimalType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default='')
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if len(self.name)>20:
            return self.name[:20] + "..."
        else:
            return self.name
```

Here is the function its being executed in:

```
@login_required
def animal_type(request, animal_type_id):
    """Shows a single animal type and all of the animals associated"""
    animal_type = AnimalType.objects.get(id=animal_type_id)
    #animal type belongs to user
    if animal_type.owner != request.user:
        raise Http404

    animals = animal_type.animals_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'animal_type':animal_type, 'animals':animals}
    return render(request, 'zoo_animal_feeders/animal_type.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `related_name` for this case is `animal_set`. I'd recommend always setting `related_name` in your relationship fields to avoid this confusion.

[Relevant docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)